# How to use primeNg virtualScroller p-table with a prepopulated List?

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to use p-table VirtualScrolling with a prepolated list but the only example that primeng website give is with a lazyload approach:

```
<p-table #table [columns]="columns" [value]="cars" [scrollable]="true"
[rows]="20" [scrollHeight]="scrollHeight" [virtualScroll]="true"
 (onLazyLoad)="loadDataOnScroll($event)" [lazy]="true" 
[totalRecords]="totalRecords" [virtualRowHeight]="30">
```

But no example is given to use p-table virtuallScrolling with a propulated list. Example for a propulated  list that doesnt use p-table.

```
<p-virtualScroller [value]="cars" scrollHeight="500px" [itemSize]="150">
    <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-car>
        Car content
    </ng-template>
</p-virtualScroller>
```

Any idea how to the same approache but with p-table ?

Thanks